# setup tomcat personal webserver

Tags: windows, servlets, tomcat

i hosted an apache server by changing few details in the httpd.conf file, used [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/#!124212/how-to-set-up-a-personal-home-web-server). i also did port forwarding so that the server is able to respond behind the wireless router (firewall), it worked completely fine ( i checked by typing the ip and port number from some other host outside the network). now i am trying to run servlets for which i need tomcat server. i have installed tomcat but i am unable to access the server from another host that is not on the same network. could somebody please guide as to how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing just as I for apache server, except that I changed the listening port to something else. added that entry in the router. incorporated tomcat in eclipse and then started the sample project. using whatismyip.com, i got the ip address. i could access my webserver from elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would go with [The Apache-Tomcat Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) and use it to connect your new tomcat instance to your Apache.